# dcdiag returning test failed and passed for same server

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

I am getting 2 different test results for the same server in `dcdiag /q /a` (for all DCs in the site) and `dcdiag /q /s:myserver`.

`dcdiag /q /a` contains: ......................... myserver failed test RidManager (the same is true for other tests)

but `dcdiag /q /s:myserver` is not showing any failures.

So I tried removing the /q switch for the above command to see whether RidManager is passing with:

`dcdiag /s:myserver`, and it is showing `myserver passed test RidManager`.

As per the command help, /a for all servers in the site and /s for testing 1 particular server.

Why are the results different, and is it pass or fail ? Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of Windows Server are your DCs running?

Comment: Windows 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

DCDIAG checks specific services while it also checks the system logs for error events. If you had a RidManager critical event in your system logs, it would show a failure in the DCDIAG output, but would still show success if the RidManager is currently functioning OK. You can test for this by running `dcdiag /a /n:DomainName /skip:systemlog`.

Have you tried clearing your DC's system log and running DCDIAG again?

Do you get the same results if you run `dcdiag /test:RidManager /s:servername` and `dcdiag /test:RidManager /a /n:DomainName`?

Comment: `dcdiag /test:RidManager /s:myserver` returned "myserver passed test RidManager" but `dcdiag /test:RidManager /a /n:DomainName` returned "myserver failed test RidManager" .If this is because  of system logs ,Is there any way to exclude system log failures in dcdiag output ?

Comment: Yes, you can run `dcdiag /a /n:DomainName /skip:systemlog`.

Comment: I tried `dcdiag /a /n:DomainName /skip:systemlog` but the output still has RidManager Failure and I observed `dcdiag /q /s:myserver` was returning **myserver failed test SystemLog**.

Comment: Was a domain controller previously demoted in that domain, or have any roles ever been seized?

Comment: No, there was no incidents like that

Comment: Try running `repadmin /showrepl dcdiag /test:ridmanager /v`. This should tell you what is wrong.